# tkinter page navigation , внутри главного Frame разместит страницы

Tags: python, tkinter

tkinter , есть несколько файлов (страниц) page1.py, page2.py, page3.py которых нужно отобразить на главной меню при нажатие соответствующей кнопки , народ как это сделать, помогите разобраться, ниже выложу меню чтоб понят суть проблемы

```
option_frame = tk.Frame(window, bg='#036bfc')
home_btn = tk.Button(option_frame, text='Home', font=('Bold',14, 'bold'), fg='#158aff', bd=0)
home_btn.place(x=10, y=30, width=105)
employee_btn = tk.Button(option_frame, text='Employee', font=('Bold',14, 'bold', command: Pages), 
fg='#158aff', bd=0, command: Pages)
employee_btn.place(x=10, y=80, width=105)

cars_btn = tk.Button(option_frame, text='Cars', font=('Bold',14, 'bold'), fg='#158aff', bd=0)
cars_btn.place(x=10, y=130, width=105)
Qr_btn = tk.Button(option_frame, text='QR reader', font=('Bold',14, 'bold'), fg='#158aff', 
bd=0)
Qr_btn.place(x=10, y=180, width=105)

def Pages():
  import page1
  pass


option_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
option_frame.pack_propagate(False)
option_frame.configure(width=125, height=700)

main_frame =tk.Frame(window, highlightbackground='black', highlightthickness=2)
main_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
main_frame.pack_propagate(False)
main_frame.configure(height=700, width=900)
window.mainloop()
```

[image: mainpage]

Comment: Создаете фреймы для каждой страницы, заполняете их. Храните в переменной какой из фреймов сейчас отображается. При нажатии на кнопку делаете pack_forget старого фрейма (если он был отображен) и pack для нужного (или аналогично grid_forget и grid).

Comment: Или просто использовать ttk.Notebook

Comment: @insolor,  не лучше ли будет вызывать отдельную страницу в главной странице ? тоесть в одном файле столько кодов , я думал что для каждого окна отдельный файл отображать будет легче отображать для GUI

Comment: "не лучше ли будет вызывать отдельную страницу в главной странице" - не понятно, что вы тут хотели сказать. Выносите создание фреймов в отдельные функции (или классы), эти функции (классы) выносите в отдельные модули. А переключение делаете как я описал выше.

Comment: @insolor, вроде понятно, спасибо буду следовать вашему совету